# Proxy Server that will interpret all incoming traffic to my PC using servlet

Tags: servlets

Can we develop Proxy Server or the application using servlet that will read all incoming and outgoing HTTP request/sresponse? if so please guide me in the direction I am new to Servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a too broad question to answer it completely here, not because it's so complicated, but much to describe (actually I am not aware what you actually know). But the web is full of "java servlet proxy" tutorials, so just put these sentences into the search engine of your choice and pick the first result.

[Here is one as an example](http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/12/simple-java-proxy-servlet-using.html). If you go through this tutorial, you already have a simple proxy implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, as suggested by you I will go through the articles first over the internet. Provided link for article is really good gave lot of understanding, Thanks.